# How can I get webform file upload to display a thumbnail instead of a link?

Tags: 7, webforms, files

I have a webform with a file field.
When I upload the file I want to return a thumbnail of the file.

Is this possible? If so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used a bit of JavaScript to replace the link with an image tag that used the path in the link for it's source.